# read multiple text file, append some html tags and then save it to user selected directory in java

Tags: java, html, file-io, tags, text-files

I want both input and output directories to be chosen by the user.

Below is the code I have tried so far:

```
public class FileOpen<FileChooser> extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
         static private final String newline = "\n";
     JButton openButton, convertButton;
     JTextArea log;
        JFileChooser fc;

    public FileOpen() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        log = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        log.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        log.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);

        // Create a file chooser
        fc = new JFileChooser();

        openButton = new JButton("Open a Text File...");

        openButton.addActionListener(this);

        convertButton = new JButton("Convert to HTML File...");

        convertButton.addActionListener(this);

        // For layout purposes, put the buttons in a separate panel
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); // use FlowLayout
        buttonPanel.add(openButton);
        buttonPanel.add(convertButton);

        // Add the buttons and the log to this panel.
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Handle open button action.
        if (e.getSource().equals(openButton)) {
            fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                    "Only Text Files", "txt");
            fc.setFileFilter(filter);

            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileOpen.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File files[] = null;

                files = fc.getSelectedFiles();

                for (int i = 0; i <= files.length - 1; i++) {
                    log.append("Opening " + files[i].getName() + "\n ");

                    try {

                        FileReader fr = new FileReader(files[i]);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                        String strLine;
                        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
                        // Read File Line By Line
                        log.append("Reading files " + files[i].getName()
                                + "\n ");
                        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                            String tokens[] = strLine.split(" ");
                            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                                fileContent.append(strLine);
                                fileContent.append("<br />");
                                FileWriter fstreamWrite = new FileWriter(
                                        files[i]);
                                fstreamWrite.write("<START>");
                                fstreamWrite.write("\n");
                                fstreamWrite.write("<TITLE> </TITLE>");
                                fstreamWrite.write("\n");
                                fstreamWrite.write("<BODY>");
                                fstreamWrite.write("\n");
                                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                                        fstreamWrite);
                                RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(
                                        files[i], "rw");
                                raf.seek(0);
                                out.write(fileContent.toString());
                                out.newLine();
                                out.write("</BODY>");
                                out.newLine();
                                out.write("<END>");
                                out.newLine();
                                System.out.println(fileContent);
                                raf.close();
                                out.flush();
                                out.close();
                                br.close();

                            }

                        }

                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } else {
                log.append("Operation Canceled \n");
            }

            // Handle Covert button action.
        } else if (e.getSource() == convertButton) {

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextToHtml");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Add content to the window.
        frame.add(new FileOpen());

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: _Here I want_ some explanation of why this isn't fine for you, what it fails to achieve, and what you tried to fix it.

Comment: 1. Open the source directory.

2. Read the files

3.For each file

a.       read the file line by line

b.      output file will be inputfile.html

c.       First line of the output file will be <START>

d.      Next line is title tag - <TITLE>Input file name without exn</TITLE>

e.      Next line will be <BODY>

f.        Page Number requirement is yet to come

g.       Each Para will be within <p></p> tag

h.      Eachline will be appended with <br> tag.

i.         Once file is complete read, add </body> tag

j.        Add <end> tag.

k.      Save the html file in target directory.

Comment: So to be clear: **we should write this code for you? For free?**

Comment: no i just want how to read multiple file in a directory at a time how to save it after editing to a user specified directory

Comment: can any body help me out for this?

Answer (score 1):

the below code works for single file and path has to be specified for both source and target, but i want it to be user selective directories, like 
  1. /Dir->
     abc.txt
     adc.txt,
select this directory for operation, make changes and again while saving user has to select destination directory to save these files with .html extension.

```
public class TextToHtml {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // Open the file that is the first

        String sourcepath = "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/Test/UAE0b143800.txt";

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(sourcepath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fstream));
        String strLine;
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
        // Read File Line By Line

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String tokens[] = strLine.split(" ");
            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                {
                    fileContent.append(strLine);
                    fileContent.append("<br />");
                }
            }
        }
        // Now fileContent will have updated content , which you can
        // override into file

        String targetpath = "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/Target/UAE0b143800.html";

        // To trim file Extension
        String title = targetpath;
        title = title.substring(0, title.lastIndexOf('.'));
        br.close();

        FileWriter fstreamWrite = new FileWriter(targetpath);
        fstreamWrite.write("<START>");
        fstreamWrite.write("\n");
        fstreamWrite.write("<TITLE>" + title + "</TITLE>");
        fstreamWrite.write("\n");
        fstreamWrite.write("<BODY>");
        fstreamWrite.write("\n");

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstreamWrite);

        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(targetpath, "rw");
        raf.seek(0);

        out.write(fileContent.toString());
        out.newLine();
        out.write("</BODY>");
        out.newLine();
        out.write("<END>");
        out.newLine();
        out.close();
        raf.close();
        // in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how can i do this for multiple files in a directory at a time?